# What are the tax implications of selling unwanted clothing online?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I bought some clothes on final sale, that ended up not fitting me. Right now they're all sitting in a closet, and I want to get rid of them. If I sell them on eBay or Grailed (presumably for a loss, I'd price them to move), is that just taxed normal income, or can I somehow escape from needing to report it?

I'm really just looking to get rid of them, I don't care about the money that much, so I'm trying to figure out if doing this is worth my time, or if I should just drop them at a Goodwill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are taxed, but you are allowed to deduct cost. So you only profit if you sell them for more than you paid. If you are truly worried about taxes, you might be better off donating them to Goodwill and writing off the donation

Comment: If that deduction results in a negative number overall, do I still need to remember to _do something_ on my tax return? Or can it be omitted entirely?

Comment: I would just omit it, but you may want to bring it up to your tax pro.